# Any way to turn cookies off for the front end?

Tags: cookies

Any way to turn cookies off for the front end?

I think it's only CraftSessionId being set, but still, anyone know?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's PHP's [session](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) cookie and is how PHP keeps track of user data across different requests. It'll only get set if something in your template ultimately invokes any of the methods in Craft's [UserSessionService](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/UserSessionService) or Yii's [CWebUser](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser).